# MVC4 Complex Type Model is null after post

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is my model

```
public class AdministrationModel
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
  public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult GetTabContent(string id)
{
  switch (id)
  {
   case "tab3":
   model = GetAllUsersInfo();
   viewName = "Administration";
   break;
   }
   return View(viewName);
 }

  private List<AdministrationModel> GetAllUsersInfo()
  {
    List<AdministrationModel> userList = new List<AdministrationModel>();
    foreach (MembershipUser user in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
      UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile.GetUserProfile(user.UserName);
      userList.Add(new AdministrationModel { EmailAddress = user.Email,                       IsApproved = user.IsApproved, FirstName = userProfile.FirstName, LastName = userProfile.LastName });
    }

    return userList;
  }
```

This is my View

```
@model List<AdminContainerModel>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Administration", "Account"))
{
  <fieldset>
    <div>
      @foreach (AdministrationModel AM in Model)
      {
        <div>
         <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => AM.FirstName)</div>
         <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => AM.LastName)</div>
         <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => AM.EmailAddress)</div>
         <div class="colPartial"><input type="checkbox" checked="@AM.IsApproved"/>            </div>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  }
</div>
 <input type="submit" value="Update Account" />
 </fieldset>
}
```

When the user clicks the Update Account button it goes to the controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Administration(List<AdministrationModel> model)
  {
     return View();
  }
```

inside this method, model is always null.  however the View that renders everything is perfect and shows what I want it to show.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using collections, in order to correctly process them so they are model-bound on post without any additional leg work, you need to make sure they are indexed correctly, you can do this by using a for loop, something like:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].LastName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmailAddress)
    <div>
        <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].FirstName)</div>
        <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].LastName)</div>
        <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].EmailAddress)</div>
        <div class="colPartial">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsApproved)</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
}
```

That should model bind without any other code :)

**Edit: Sorry I forgot, displayFors by default don't put the correct properties on for model binding, added hiddenFors for the other fields that don't have an editorFor**

**Edit2: Based on your other question in the comment, if it was public facing and you didn't want them to change any of the hidden for values using the dev tools, try the following:**

Ok so you don't want them to change the hiddenFors, that's fine, but you will need some sort of ID so you know which client is which when the data is posted, I suggest that instead of having these in the above code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].FirstName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].LastName)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].EmailAddress)
```

Replace them with:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ClientId)
```

That way you're not posting back the firstname, lastname or email address, just a reference to the actual client that is ticked, unticked.

**To answer your other question in the comment about keeping track of the original values,  in your controller method you can just go and get the original values from the database, then here's how you can detect which ones are different, something like:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Administration(List<AdministrationModel> model)
{
    var originalMatches = GetAllUsersInfo();

    var differences = (from o in originalMatches
                      join c in model on o.ClientId equals c.ClientId
                      where c.IsApproved != o.IsApproved).ToList()

    return View();
}
```

Comment: it does not for me.  In the post back event - all the values for first name, last name and Email address are null.  I want a collection of all the ones that have changed (either the checkbox went from checked to unchecked or unchecked to checked)

Comment: Sorry check my edit, I forgot displayFors don't put the Name properties on fields to correctly model bind (we changed our template to do that). In the controller you could just filter out on non checked in link so something like var clients = model.Where(c => c.IsApproved).ToList()

Comment: it worked awesome, however i have 2 questions regarding this: 1. if someone changes the hidden field value (dev tools in almost every browser) then the value in the model changes too 2. the lamda expression only gives the list of all the checked ones, how can I keep track of the ones that were already checked and that were checked in this session

Comment: Cool. 1. Is it a public facing website that you don't want to allow people to manipulate? 2. You could just make your model a complex type containing two lists of clients, one that you're editing and the original one. Repeat the above for loop for both collections, but just have all hidden fields for the original collection.

Comment: 1. Yes it is a public facing website where people should not be allowed to changed anything :). 2. I am not sure I understand what you mean.  I am very new to MVC

Comment: 1. Check my edit, instead of putting hidden fields for all those fields, you could just have a hidden for that is a field that you can use to identify each client (I've used ClientId). 2. Check my edit, in the controller I get all the original values and show you how to calculate the differences using LINQ :)

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you! replacing foreach with for fixed the binding.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@model` directive is incorrect, it should be the fully qualified type name.

In this case:

```
 @model TheNamespace.AdministrationModel
```

---

After your updated question.

Try using:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model)
```

This will call a specialized **Editor Template** for your list.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Comment: are you talking about the View?  if so, i just removed the namespace to post it on here.  The display view has no problem showing the data, its during the HTTPPost call that the model is null

Comment: did you want me to replace DisplayFor with EditorFor?  I tried that and my model is still null after post.  I am sure I am missing something (just not sure what it is)

Comment: You need an EditorTemplate View that maps the `AdministrationModel`. `Html.EditorFor(Model)` will look for this view. There is no need to loop through the list once you use this.

Comment: Ok, I kind of got it to work this way.  However, this renders everything in the model as an editable field.  All I want to be editable is the "IsApproved" checkbox.  Once that is checked/unchecked, I need to lookup the user based on the email address and update him/her.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: there may be attributes you can set on the on the properties of the viewmodel that signify themselves as "non-editable" - this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876371/mvc-dataannotations-how-to-make-field-no-editable-in-3-5

Comment: ok I am sorry to keep bothering, but "EditorFor" and "TextBoxFor" updates the ViewModel to have the data on the View.  I used the "readonly" property @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.FirstName, new { @readonly = "readonly" }) like this.  I cant understand how to just display the value as a label and not in a text box (both TextboxFor and EditorFor seems to put the value in a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return list items with the model on submit you will need to use a for loop, not a foreach

Comment: this should be a comment

Comment: if all he changed was the foreach to for it would work, so it is a solution

Comment: well the thing is you're just 'pointing something out' - an answer should be deeper than this

Comment: sorry, i guess i wanted to be polite by recognizing the accepted answer before writing my solution. I reworded it to meet your standards even though the content is just the same.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me - look at the accepted answer for this question.  there's a lot of content that explains the answer as well as providing the solution.  That's not always necessary, but if what you want to say can fit into the comment box and has no code/stuff that needs formatting - then the comment box is the place for it

Comment: I understand what you are trying to get at, and I understand the importance of keeping related input in the comments section. But my answer is not related to the accepted answer so that is why i posted it as a new answer to the question.

Comment: So i came here to this thread with the same exact question. None of the answers stated here had the answer for me. a little later i found out that foreach loops dont work, you need to use for loops. So the current answer did not help me at all.
If i post this as a comment then anyone in the future who comes to this thread with the same question will (very likely) not see it. So i made it an answer. For the simple fact that someone could find a unique answer to their question in my post i feel justified.

Answer (score 0):

Matty's answer will work.

If you want to avoid having to specify indexes (which wouldn't work if you had an ICollection) you can define a child template as Xander has explained.

The benefit is you still get all your strong typed intellisense in the AdminContainerModel View and MVC hooks the items back in to your List on post back for you out of the box.

Here's an example:

Main Editor template (as Xander said):

```
    @model IEnumerable<AdminContainerModel>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Administration", "Account"))
    {
      <fieldset>
        <div>
          @Html.EditorForModel()
        </div?
      </fieldset>
    }
```

AdminContainerModel Editor template(This is called for each item in your List because you've called @Html.EditorForModel:

```
@model AdminContainerModel
<div>
    <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => AM.FirstName)</div>
    <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => AM.LastName)</div>
    <div class="colFull">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => AM.EmailAddress)</div>
    <div class="colPartial"><input type="checkbox" checked="@AM.IsApproved"/>            
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```