# Passing only selected values in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application where I would like to assign zero or more project types to a particular file.  I am rendering a page where there is a row for each file and a column with a checkbox for each project type.  Something like this:

File1   |  Translate ☐   | Edit ☐

File2   |  Translate ☐   | Edit ☐

To render this I have created a ViewModel that contains a single file and a list of project types:

```
public class FileProject
{
    public File ProjectFile = new File();
    public List<ProjectType> ProjectTypes = new List<ProjectType>();
}
```

And I pass a list of these to my view:

```
@model List<MyVerbalInk.ViewModels.FileProject>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Assign", "Order")) {
    @foreach (var f in @Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @f.ProjectFile.FileName
            </td>
            <td>
                @for(int i = 0; i < @f.ProjectTypes.Count; i++)
                {
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        @Html.CheckBox("projectTypeId", new { value = @f.ProjectTypes[i].ProjectTypeId }) @f.ProjectTypes[i].Name
                    </label>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

When this posts I would like to get a list of FileProject objects where the ProjectTypes only contain the ones that have been checked:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Assign(List<FileProject> fileProjects)
    {
        //Do stuff
        return View();
    }
```

But the `fileProjects` parameter is always null.  How can I pass back a collection of FileProject objects that only contains the `ProjectTypes` that have been checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you test to change your BeginForm with that :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Assign", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
```

**EDIT: another question with exactly the same problem : [MVC4 Complex Type Model is null after post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218209/mvc4-complex-type-model-is-null-after-post)**

Comment: Just to clarify - it's getting to my Post method.  The parameter is just null.

Comment: Ok so after a little bit of testing of what was wrong, I found exactly an other post which had your problem, here :[Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218209/mvc4-complex-type-model-is-null-after-post)
I tested the correct answer and your fileProjects is not empty ;)

Comment: @Kenta is correct, the problem is with your naming and indexing of the checkbox fields. Change the names and index them and you should get the behavior your expecting

Comment: Along with what Lee Harrison said, I would strongly recommend using `@Html.CheckBoxFor()`. That should take care of the naming for you.